# Most efficient way to integrate $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{4\sin^2 x - 4\sin x + 1}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\pi \sqrt{4\sin^2 x - 4\sin x + 1}\,dx$$

Please help with this.
I cannot do this problem in a definite way.

Comment: The integrand is $\sqrt{(2\sin x-1)^2}$.

Comment: @ JohnD Then,i know that |2sinx-1|.But,the problem is after that.

Comment: Hint: Separate into three parts, $0$ to $\pi/6$, $\pi/6$ to $5\pi/6$, the rest. On the first part our function is $1-2\sin x$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt {4\sin^2 x - 4\sin x + 1}\,dx = 2\sqrt{\sin^2 x - \sin x + \frac 14}\,dx$$
$$=2\int_0^\pi \sqrt{\left (\sin x - \frac{1}2\right)^2}\,dx $$

$$= 2\int_0^\pi \left|\sin x - \frac 12\right|\, dx$$

$$=  2\int_0^{\pi/6} \left(\frac 12 - \sin x\right)\,dx + 2\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} \left(\sin x - \frac 12\right)\,dx + 2\int_{5\pi/6}^\pi \left(\frac 12 - \sin x\right)\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

We get to

$$ I = \int_0^\pi \sqrt{4\sin^2x-4\sin x+1}\;dx = \int_0^\pi \mid 2\sin{x}-1 \mid dx  $$

as can be shown by factoring the radicand into $(2\sin{x}-1)^2$. The problem now arises of picking our bounds. First set $2\sin{x} - 1 = 0$ to find $\sin{x} = 1/2$. On our interval of $[0,\pi]$ we see our solutions are $x_0 = \pi/6,\ x_1=5\pi/6$. Plugging in these values we see the expression $2\sin{x}-1$ is negative on $[0.\pi/6]$ and $[5\pi/6,\pi]$, which is where we get our bounds. Now we have

$$I = -\int_{0}^{\pi/6} (2\sin{x}-1)\ dx + \int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6} (2\sin{x}-1)\ dx - \int_{5\pi/6}^{\pi} (2\sin{x}-1)\ dx   $$

which one could evaluate directly given

$$\int (2\sin{x} - 1)\ dx = -2\cos{x} - x + C$$

The exact form I get is $I = 4(\sqrt{3}-1) - \pi/3$